# Best match REGEXP pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to look for 3 kinds of formats that might occur in a string (A = Letter; # = digit):

```
A###A
A####
A#####
```

Example:

```
This booking has the ID of A#####.
```

The string can contain only one of the three example patterns. I wrote this REGEXP with OR operators, so I can check and extract the IDs I need:

```
([a-zA-Z]\d{4})|([a-zA-Z]\d{3}[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z]\d{5})
```

The problem is, that it does not return the best match from the REGEXP, but the first match. For example, if the string contains `A#####`, it will return `A####`, ignoring the last digit – becaused it already matched a pattern before.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put `([a-zA-Z]\d{5})` as the first alternative. Or use `[a-zA-Z]\d{4,5}|[a-zA-Z]\d{3}[a-zA-Z]`. Enclose with word boundaries if needed, `\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\d{4,5}|[a-zA-Z]\d{3}[a-zA-Z])\b`

Comment: It should be in order, longest matches first.

Comment: pff, I should've thought about the order... thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\d{3}(?:[a-zA-Z]|\d{1,2})\b
```

`[a-zA-Z]\d{3}` - constant part

`([a-zA-Z]|\d{1,2})` -  letter, one or tow digits

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LgZ4ww/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for matching 5 characters before you match for 4 characters.
This way it will always detect 5 before it detects 4.
You can just switch the 5 and 4.

```
([a-zA-Z]\d{5})|([a-zA-Z]\d{4})|([a-zA-Z]\d{3}[a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.